# How to do base64 encoding in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I'm stucking with this problem.

Is there anyway to encode string to base64 in Jekyll?

I want to make json files for every posts in my blog before or after I push the codes to Github Pages.

```
- 2017-08-26-post1.md
- 2017-08-26-post1.md

- 2017-08-26-post1.json
- 2017-08-26-post1.json
```

maybe something like `{{ some_string | base64_encoded }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own liquid tag and supply your string as parameter. Then convert that string to base64 using ruby https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html and output it to your page.

Something like this may help, which was an example I found here - https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/04/custom-jekyll-tags.html:

```
class AdsInlineTag < Liquid::Tag
  def initialize(tag_name, input, tokens)
    super
    @input = input
  end

  def render(context)
    # Split the input variable (omitting error checking)
    input_split = split_params(@input)
    adclient = input_split[0].strip
    adslot = input_split[1].strip

    # Write the output HTML string
    output =  "<div style=\"margin: 0 auto; padding: .8em 0;\"><script async "
    output += "src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\">"
    output += "</script><ins class=\"adsbygoogle\" style=\"display:block\" data-ad-client=\"#{adclient}\""
    output += "data-ad-slot=\"#{adslot}\" data-ad-format=\"auto\"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle ="
    output += "window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></div>"

    # Render it on the page by returning it
    return output;
  end

  def split_params(params)
    params.split("|")
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('ads', AdsInlineTag)
```

Hope this helps, I will try and make a simple base64 liquid tag for jekyll and will update if I get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an working base64 filter written in Ruby:

```
require "base64"

module Base64Filter
  def base64_encode (input)
    Base64.encode64(input)
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Base64Filter) # register filter globally
```

In jekyll create a new file `base64_filter.rb` and put it in the `_plugins` folder in your root. A server restart is needed if you are in `serve` mode.

Then you can use it with e.g.:

```
{{ site.email | base64_encode }}
```

**Note:** Github Pages does not support plugins!